# I need a field to choose a value from a list, and then have that value no longer be an option to choose from that list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, list-form

I would like to have an inventory list and then have a field in my main SharePoint show those values to choose. But I would like the chosen value to no longer show on the next entry since it's already taken. Can someone point me in the direction on where to start something like this?

Comment: I'm thinking I need to utilize External Data. I haven't seen any other options thus far https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-external-data-676e60e7-d99f-463f-a173-65e9d63538c0#__toc353550771

Answer (score 1):

Guess.. you are looking for a look up column kind of thing with Unique Values. First prepare a list (Inventory list) and then in main SharePoint List create a column of Lookup type. You will get option to select which list values you want( select your Inventory list) and select column contains unique value.

Once created, you will see the Inventory List data on your lookup column. You will see all the data, but end users will not be able to select the already submitted one since you have selected to take only unique values.

Comment: What type of field should the inventory list be though? I actually tried this, but used a Choice field type but apparently Lookup doesn't work with a Choice field.

Comment: Try with a single line column and fill as many inventory items you have.

Comment: Hmm...separated by commas? I see if I choose Multiple Line column, you cannot enforce unique values.